# Why is lead's first ionisation enthalpy greater than that of tin?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ionization-energy

Using Slater's rule, I found that both lead and tin's $Z_\mathrm{eff}$ for 6p and 5p electrons equal. However, the ionisation energy is different. Is comparing ionisation enthalpy on the basis of $Z_\mathrm{eff}$ not correct?

Also, I found [Clementi-Raimondi Effective Nuclear Charge](http://www.knowledgedoor.com/2/elements_handbook/clementi-raimondi_effective_nuclear_charge.html) which probably explains the trend, but why is this different to Slater's rule?

Comment: Perhaps Slater's rule is more of a suggestion.

Comment: This is an example of a relativistic effect, so Clementi-Raimondi effective nuclear charges (non-relativistic in nature) likely also cannot describe the behaviour adequately. You may find [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/7142/1499) tangentially useful.